# Including and altering a .txt input in LaTeX

Tags: verbatim

I am using `\usepackage{verbatim}` to show a .txt file in my LaTeX document, via `\verbatiminput{<path to .txt>}`. And this works fine. However, the data that I display looks like this:

```
5.35    0.35    5.61    -0.39   6.84    -0.16   
5.45    0.45    5.52    -0.48   6.84    -0.16   
5.45    0.45    5.51    -0.49   6.96    -0.04   
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.96    -0.04   
5.47    0.47    5.63    -0.37   6.96    -0.04   
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.84    -0.16       
5.35    0.35    5.63    -0.37   6.84    -0.16   
5.47    0.47    5.51    -0.49   6.96    -0.04
```

I would like to have a colour scheme: I want every odd column to have a light-gray background. And I would like this table to be centered as well. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please adda compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question?

Comment: Take a look at pgfplotstable heat map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in your table and process it as a `tabular` after splitting each line at spaces, which are next substituted with `&`.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.dat}
5.35    0.35    5.61    -0.39   6.84    -0.16   
5.45    0.45    5.52    -0.48   6.84    -0.16   
5.45    0.45    5.51    -0.49   6.96    -0.04   
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.96    -0.04   
5.47    0.47    5.63    -0.37   6.96    -0.04   
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.84    -0.16       
5.35    0.35    5.63    -0.37   6.84    -0.16   
5.47    0.47    5.51    -0.49   6.96    -0.04
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.dat}
5.35    0.35    5.61    -0.39   6.84
5.45    0.45    5.52    -0.48   6.84
5.45    0.45    5.51    -0.49   6.96
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.96
5.47    0.47    5.63    -0.37   6.96
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.84
5.35    0.35    5.63    -0.37   6.84
5.47    0.47    5.51    -0.49   6.96
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tableinput}{m}
 {
  \tableinput_main:n { #1 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g__tableinput_file_ior
\tl_new:N \l__tableinput_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__tableinput_row_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tableinput_main:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__tableinput_body_tl
  \ior_open:Nn \g__tableinput_file_ior { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__tableinput_file_ior
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tableinput_row_seq { ~ } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__tableinput_row_seq \l_tmpa_tl % last item is blank
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__tableinput_body_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l__tableinput_row_seq { & } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__tableinput_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g__tableinput_file_ior
  \begin{center}\ttfamily
  \int_if_odd:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__tableinput_row_seq }
   {
    \begin{tabular}
     {
      *{ \int_eval:n { (\seq_count:N \l__tableinput_row_seq - 1) /2 } }
       {>{\columncolor{gray!30}}r r}
      >{\columncolor{gray!30}}r
     }
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}
     {
      *{ \int_eval:n { (\seq_count:N \l__tableinput_row_seq) /2 } }
       {>{\columncolor{gray!30}}r r}
     }
   }
   \tl_use:N \l__tableinput_body_tl
   \end{tabular}
   \end{center}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableinput{\jobname-1.dat}

\tableinput{\jobname-2.dat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to change to the `listings` package you can use the add-on package `lstlinebgrd` as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.txt}
5.35    0.35    5.61    -0.39   6.84    -0.16   
5.45    0.45    5.52    -0.48   6.84    -0.16   
5.45    0.45    5.51    -0.49   6.96    -0.04   
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.96    -0.04   
5.47    0.47    5.63    -0.37   6.96    -0.04   
5.45    0.45    5.63    -0.37   6.84    -0.16       
5.35    0.35    5.63    -0.37   6.84    -0.16   
5.47    0.47    5.51    -0.49   6.96    -0.04
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{RGB}{220, 220, 220}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linebackgroundcolor={\ifodd\value{lstnumber}\color{mylightgray}\fi}]{myfile.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx so much, leandriis! This looks so much better already. But now every odd row / line is colored. I would like to color every odd column. I was google searching a `columnbackgroundcolor` command but I think this does not exist

Comment: @user503842: I completely overlooked the "column" in your question and somehow thought you were interested in coloring rows instead. Maybe you can use the `datatool` package to achieve the output you are looking for.